# Openswan IPSec connection (to a cisco asa) disconnects every 18 hours

Tags: cisco, ipsec

We have a CentOS 5.5 (vm) with Linux Openswan U2.6.32 installed. On it, we have an IPSec tunnel with a peer that is a cisco asa. The tunnel disconnects every 18 hours (we need the tunnel to stay up all the time).

We have tested many setups at the openswan but currently we have the following configuration:

```
    auto=start
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ike
    authby=secret
    rightrsasigkey=%cert
    leftrsasigkey=%cert 
    compress=no 
    esp=aes256-sha1
    ike=aes256-sha1-modp1536       
    pfs=no
    ikelifetime=24h
    keylife=1h
    dpddelay=2
    dpdtimeout=1000
    dpdaction=restart
    rekey=yes
```

We do not have access to the peer device.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance you have some misalignment with the Cisco ASA around one of the tunnel metrics, for example a common misalignment is around the the ipsec session timeout (not the ike session which you configured for 24h)
in this case the missing property from your config is 
salifetime=18h

Once both sides are aligned rekey will happen properly

Other suggestions:

a) reduce the dpdtimeout to something much lower that 1000secs (the common setups are between 30 sec to 3 min)
if this doesn't help, you might want to recheck how the ASA is configured making sure it's not set to drop the tunnel every n Kb or when the tunnel is ideal

b) change the dpdaction from restart to restart_by_peer